# jQuery: click event inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to fire a click event on the click of an element inside an iframe, but it doesn't seem to be working. My current set up: 
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4aa3/ 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#this-iframe').load(function () {
        $('#this-iframe').contents().find('img').live({
            click: function () {
                alert('clicked img');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Clicking on the image inside the iframe isn't firing the alert, I'm not sure why, or is there a better way to achieve this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the iframe contains a page from a different domain,in this case the jsfiddle result frame is loaded from `fiddle.jshell.net` and your iframe is loading `jsfiddle.net` which means they are different domains so you do not have access to it. Also jQuery's `.load` function loads in data from a url, it is not a onload event. [jQuery load docs](http://api.jquery.com/load)

Comment: @PatrickEvans `.load()` is also used to handle the load event: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes I understand that, the jsFiddle is just a demo of my setup. The domain I'm using this on, the iFrame content is also from the same domain, thus I have access to it. But this click function still isn't working.

Comment: @JasonP Ahh I see. user1374796, even though there is a load event available, it does not get called on iframes so you will need some other method to know when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have the iframe on the same domain, you can use this script to catch clicks in the iframe. Don't use .live, it is depriciated as of jQuery 1.7.

```
var iframeBody = $('body', $('#iframe')[0].contentWindow.document);
$(iframeBody).on('click', 'img', function(event) {
    doSomething();
});
```

You can manipulate the body through the iframeBody variable.